Why are epiglottal consonants easier to do lying on your back?
I was watching a Youtube video(1) on how to pronounce the Arabic letters 'ayn (ع; commonly called a "voiced pharyngeal fricative" but per Ladefoged more often a creaky epiglottal approximant) and its voiceless counterpart ḥāʾ (ح; a voiceless epiglottal fricative).  The author recommends tilting back one's neck as if for gargling, or else lying on one's back, when approaching these sounds, as they are easier to produce in that position.
Feeling sceptical, I tried it and found to my surprise that the difference was very clear.
What is it about epiglottal consonants that changes with a tilted position? Something to do with the aryepiglottic folds?
1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-oA0HfNUezI
